# performance in 4.5 create gsi index

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have below query.

```
SELECT DailyCampaignUsage.day date, sum (ARRAY_SUM(DailyCampaignUsage.`statistics`[*].clicks)) clicks,   
sum (ARRAY_SUM(DailyCampaignUsage.`statistics`[*].clicksCost)) revenue   
FROM Inheritx DailyCampaignUsage 
JOIN Inheritx Campaign ON KEYS ('Campaign|'||TOSTRING(DailyCampaignUsage.campaignId))  
JOIN Inheritx Users on keys('User|'|| TOSTRING(Campaign.`user`))     
WHERE DailyCampaignUsage._type='DailyCampaignUsage'  and      
DATE_PART_MILLIS(STR_TO_MILLIS(DailyCampaignUsage.day),'year')=2016       
and DATE_PART_MILLIS(STR_TO_MILLIS(DailyCampaignUsage.day),'month')=5  
group by DailyCampaignUsage.day
order by DailyCampaignUsage.day
```

I have no only index on _type 
like

```
CREATE INDEX `Ottoman__type` ON `Inheritx`(`_type`)
```

when I run above query it is taking **10s**

When I try to create some index like

```
  CREATE INDEX `dailyCampaignUsage_type_clicks_cost` ON  
 `Inheritx`(_type,day,`statistics`[*].clicks,`statistics`[*].clicksCost) WHERE
 `_type` = "DailyCampaignUsage"  USING GSI
```

But It is not working it taking more time 13s.
I have also use use index (dailyCampaignUsage_type_clicks_cost)
But do not work.

which Index should I create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you post the sample document, EXPLAIN output, and how many documents you have, couchbase version, cluster setup (all services on same node, or using MDS-multi dimensional scaling) etc.

You may want to try including the year, month as index keys..

CREATE INDEX `dailyCampaignUsage_type_clicks_cost` ON
 `Inheritx`(_type, DATE_PART_MILLIS(STR_TO_MILLIS(DailyCampaignUsage.day),'year'), DATE_PART_MILLIS(STR_TO_MILLIS(DailyCampaignUsage.day),'month'), day...) WHERE ...

Comment: I have 50k+ document 
I am using 4.5 community server.
Data RAM Quota:3520
Data RAM Quota:512
Full Text RAM Quota:469
only one node

Comment: hi @krishnpatel, pls post what the exact query/index you tried. And, also the sample docs and explain output.  Check the EXPLAIN output, and make sure you can use covering index.

Comment: I will explain it latter. now I am posting other question

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482725/performance-improve-in-n1ql-couchbase-using-index