# Index not improve speed in couchbase 4.5

Tags: couchdb, sql++

I have below query

```
SELECT day,count(DISTINCT campaignId) campaigns
FROM Inheritx use index(daily_type_1)
where _type='DailyCampaignUsage'
group by day
```

I have below index

```
 `CREATE INDEX `daily_type_1` ON `Inheritx` 
(`_type`,`day`,(distinct (`campaignId`))) WHERE (`_type` = "DailyCampaignUsage")`
```

it is taking **3s** and I habe 52k data whare _type= "DailyCampaignUsage"

how I Can improve it's speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your index as follows.

```
CREATE INDEX `daily_type_1` ON `Inheritx` (campaignId,`day`)
WHERE (`_type` = "DailyCampaignUsage");
```

Keep the index in this answer. Modify your query as follows.

```
SELECT day,count(DISTINCT campaignId) campaigns
FROM Inheritx use index(daily_type_1)
where _type='DailyCampaignUsage'
and campaignId is not null
group by day;
```

Comment: it is not scan this index. it is doing PrimaryScan

Comment: when i add (_type,campaignId,`day`) only then it is working but taking 3s